# How to create 2d Array containing 2d Arraylist? (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, 2d

I want to create a 2D matrix which should contain List of lists. How Can i do it in Java?

Comment: `List<List<Integer>>`

Comment: the 2d array should contain the list of list ie. the object that you have described to create.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
List<List<String>> example = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Comment: It will create a list of list of strings but I want to create a 2d array which can contain this object;